# UI of App on iOS7 looks Like UI on iOS 6

Tags: ios

As i need my application to run on both `iOS 6` and `iOS 7`, i have set my "`iOS deployment target`" under "`Project`" as well as "`Targets`" to `iOS 6.0`. However, after doing this, when i create an `ipa file` and install it on my `iPad` (that runs on `iOS 7`), i see everything converted to the look of `iOS 6` - the searchbar, the keyboard etc etc.. Why is this happening??

I thought that on `iOS 7`, all my `UIComponents` will look as intended in `iOS 7` and same thing will happen in case of `iOS 6`, when i run it on a device that is running on `iOS 6`! why is everything messing up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was: I still had iOS 6.1 sdk on my system even when i upgraded to xcode 5. deleting the older version of sdk and cleaning and building my target solved my problem..

Answer (score 2):

Likely it depends on the `Base SDK` that you selected.

If you are using Xcode 5: select your project on the left panel, then click tab `Build Settings`, check that your `Base SDK` is "Latest iOS (iOS 7)".

You should always use the latest sdk as `Base SDK`, it represents the SDK used to build your app against.
If you want to support old iOS, you should just change the `Deployment Target`

Check it for both your `target` and `project`, since target overrides project settings

Comment: is Base SDK iOS 7 for both project\target?. Are you using Xcode 5, correct?

Comment: Yes i am using xcode 5. I can find the "base sdk" option only under "Project". It is not under "target"

Comment: well you should see it also on target, and it could be the problem since generally speaking a "target" setting override the "project" setting.